# What happened to my clothes?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In "Animal Crossing New Leaf," I time-warped to October 31st, the day of Halloween. I tried to win at a game of rock-paper-scissors with Wolfgang, but I lost, and he changed my Blue-zap outfit to a patched shirt. What happens to my clothes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Halloween, villagers in your town will ask you for candy. If you don't give them any and choose "Trick", they will **play a trick on you** if you **lose** a game of charades or rock-paper-scissors against them.

When the villagers play tricks on you, they might **transform** your currently worn shirt **into a Patched Shirt**.

Comment: lol you are giving answers to all my questions!

Comment: @JerryRox Hahah, yeah, I play a whole lot of ACNL. I'm just really glad I can help!

Comment: Do you lose the shirt when it gets transformed? Obviously you can re-buy it from the catalog but will anything convert it back?

Comment: @Reafexus I haven't ever encountered a way to transform the shirt back, and I've found no records of it happening to anyone else. So yes, it's lost and you'll have to re-buy it.